# Why is keep on return 0 for the result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, parameters

I am new to c# ASP.NET and i want to checking the database value with the value insert for login part and i did everything correctly but why am i still keep on getting that the value is incorrect while i enter the same value with the one in my database...any idea? and my rows count for dt keep on getting 0... is it anything wrong when i add the parameters?

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment6\Assignment6\App_Data\photoCompetition.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE email='@useremail' and password='@password'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@useremail", SqlDbType.Text).Value = emailtext.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Text).Value = passwordtext.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Membermenu.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Your username and password is incorrect";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    emailtext.Text = "";
                    passwordtext.Text = "";
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use parameters you don't need to set single quotes to string, remove quotes in query

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment6\Assignment6\App_Data\photoCompetition.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE email=@useremail and password=@password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@useremail", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = emailtext.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = passwordtext.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Membermenu.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Your username and password is incorrect";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    emailtext.Text = "";
                    passwordtext.Text = "";
                }
        }
```

Comment: i already try but i am getting this error The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: What's the data type of email and password columns ? What database is this ? MS SQLServer ?

Comment: is varchar and the database is MSSQL Server

Comment: Then why do you use SqlDbType.Text ? Change it to SqlDbType.Varchar

Answer (score 0):

I looks like something with your connection string, your code work without changes only connection string

```
public class TestSQLConnection
{
      static string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

    public  void TestConnection()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE email=@useremail and password=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@useremail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "David";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Fawzy";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exist");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Exist");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="TestDB" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;Integrated Security=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```